# How can I synchronize my two Mac Computers?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization

I have a Macbook and an iMac, generally I work on my Macbook, but sometimes I need that information on my iMac. My OS is Mac OSX Snow Leopard.

Comment: There are a lot of different sharing options. To make a recommendation more information concerning frequency, content, working mode, technical connectivity (WiFi, LAN, Internet) etc. would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [ChronoSync](http://www.econtechnologies.com/pages/cs/chrono_overview.html) for documents and DropBox for essentials. Dropbox has my notes, 1Password, etc and is used to share between all devices. For documents and other work, I have ChronoSync pointing at my documents folder and code folders to sync between my laptop and desktop. In my case, whenever I switch between the two computers, I just run the sync on the laptop while on the LAN with the desktop before continuing. All changes on each machine are synched to the latest version on both.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to sync your files and document, give [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) a try.

Comment: I second this, however the free 2gb may not be enough for many people. Another alternative available soon will be Cubby https://www.cubby.com/ which has device to device synchronisation as well as cloud space. Worth keeping an eye out for.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your usage scenarios (which you don't specify), I use the built-in [rsync](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rsync.1.html) command to perform a one-way sync of files from one machine to another connected to the same network.

Alternatively, if you want full two-way synchronization (that is, sync changes made on either computer) then [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/docs.html) (free/donationware) also works well.

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar setup (imac & macbook air)

my experienced recommendation is to use

- mobile me or icloud to sync email, contacts, calendars, bookmarks, etc… (google could be a substitute)
- dropbox for files, documents, pictures & some application preferences (textexpander)
- notational velocity with simplenote sync for notes
- *if something was still missing  can access the imac from parallels desktop via the iphone app (or any other remote desktop application)