# How can I sync my entire home directory between my MacBook Pro to my Mac Pro

Tags: data-synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best option to keep Laptop and Desktop user account in Sync?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53333/what-is-the-best-option-to-keep-laptop-and-desktop-user-account-in-sync)

I take my MacBook Pro with me to work and meetings. I do most of my design and development work on the Mac Pro. I currently use Google Drive and sync my documents and other things to the cloud.

However, how can I get my applications and entire home directory to sync as well, with or without the use of Google Drive? Is rsync an option to move all of `/Applications` and `~`?

I am running the latest version of OS X Lion.

My MacBook Pro connects via Gigabit Ethernet every night to run a Time Machine backup to my SAN array.

Comment: Cross-site duplicates: [1](http://superuser.com/questions/40164/sharing-or-syncing-home-folders-between-macs) [2](http://superuser.com/questions/34594/how-to-synchronise-filesystem-between-2-macs) [3](http://superuser.com/questions/62310/automatically-sync-two-computers-on-os-x) [4](http://superuser.com/questions/60398/two-identical-macs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't try it except on PC in 2006 but this kind of software do it for you :
http://fullsync.sourceforge.net/index.php

or something like this : http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/31752/fsync-for-mac-os-x