# Time Machine sync over multiple Macs

Tags: backup, time-machine, data-synchronization, restore

I have 3 MacBooks and I made a Time Machine on one of them e.g macA and then restore it on the others macB and macC. Now I did some changes on macA (added files, deleted apps,...) and did a Time Machine backup again (incremental on the previous one). Is there a way to restore these changes on macB and macC without having to do a full Time Machine restore? Like I want the 3 Macs to be synchronised and similar to each other. Any advice?

Comment: IMHO, Time Machine is _not_ the way to accomplish this. Not knowing the full explanation of _why_ you want to keep three Macs in sync, and _what_ needs synching, it's hard to come up with a definitive (or close to definitive) answer. Is it data in the standard Users folder structure that needs to be replicated, or files and folders _outside_ this structure?

Comment: I would advice against the use of Time Machine as a syncing solution in general (just use `rsync` instead). You might be able to use `tmutil compare` for a one-off though.

Comment: @IconDaemon I want to keep the files and folders similar across them.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific about which files/folders specifically?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52259/how-can-i-synchronize-my-two-mac-computers

Comment: @nohillside I want all my folders like user folders (Desktop, documents, downloads,..) As well as application folder and settings...

Comment: This sounds like an ideal candidate for the built-in iCloud sync - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh36832/10.15/mac/10.15

Comment: Most likely you will be better off using a dedicated sync app like ChronoSync, rather than trying to coerce Time Machine into doing something that it was not designed for.  This is especially true if you plan on syncing these systems often.

Comment: And which is the best amoung dropbox, icloud or other cloud platforms you think is the best?

Comment: I've been using Dropbox for myself since it came out, or shortly thereafter. You should consider [Dropbox Business](https://www.dropbox.com/business) for its file/document sharing and collaborative functions. I'm still not sure if you want to share files & documents with a group of people; trying to set up a kiosk system where multiple macs are identical; or trying to set up a user lab where multiple people login and use a free Mac. Who uses these Macs?

Comment: @IconDaemon these 3 macbooks are personal, I leave one at work sometimes then I have one at home and an older one. So they are all personal not lab setup, I just want to be able to set up one of them and make a time machine for it then restore it in the other two and then synchronize the 3 so I can use any of them any time without having to worry about different settings, files and folders