# Sync multiple macs together (which is better iCloud, Dropbox, Google Drive or OneDrive?)

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, dropbox, google-apps

I have 3 MacBooks and I made a Time Machine on one of them e.g macA and then restore it on the others macB and macC. Now I want to keep the 3 Macs in sync where if I did some changes on any mac (added files, deleted apps,...) then it will be reflected on the other two.
I have checked and there are many options like iCloud, Dropbox, Google drive or OneDrive. and I read some links but it’s confusing to have a summary of the pros and cons of each one and which one is the best, so it will be appreciated to know from experience of people here what they think is the best option? since it will be good to have some advice to try avoid choosing one and having to switch to another later on.

I've been looking into this and I was testing how iCloud sharing works and found out that if I shared a folder to anyone with read only access they still have to create an iCloud account which is very inconvenient since many people who are not Mac/iPhone users don't have one. But also the good thing with iCloud is that I have an iPhone and backing it up with iCloud is a convenience. So I am really confused with which option to go with could people please advise me with what they think is best from their experience?

I want to know the best option for me if this is what I am looking for:

- Easy smooth syncing of folders across my Macs (Documents, Desktop, Photos,...)
- Share files and folders with other people without the need of them to create a new account on the cloud platform so they can just download it, which I think is not possible with iCloud.
- I can backup my iPhone to the cloud as well (with iCloud it can be easily done), but it's not mandatory.
- The are all laptops so they are not on the same network so I guess a cloud based solution is best
- The sync is done instantly so that I don't have to start it every time I open one of the laptops.

Comment: There are Apps available to keep a group of Macs in sync as you describe but those are designed to be applied in classroom situations where you have a master image (or Mac) as the source and all others are wiped nightly (or weekly...) and the master image re-applied to the other Macs. I am not aware of anything that will keep all the settings, documents and applications in sync like you want. I use Dropbox to keep my *documents, Pictures, etc.* in sync over multiple computers but everything? I don't think that is possible.

Comment: @SteveChambers Thanks for your comment. So if I wanted to sync all user folders (desktop, documents, applications,...) you think Dropbox is the best option? I mean better than iCloud and GoogleDrive?

Comment: **No,** Dropbox (or OneDrive, or Google Drive, or...) will keep a *folder* on your Mac in sync with all computers that are also signed into it with the same ID. They will **NOT** sync all user folders. However you can put everything you would normally put in the Documents, Pictures, Music, Movies, into that folder and sync them (which is what I do) but it won't sync the Desktop (iCloud drive will, I think) or any of the other "Library" folders where bookmarks, mail and other user data is kept. I would advise looking into what iCloud drive can do for you. It may be enough for you.

Comment: @SteveChambers I thought with Dropbox I can mark what folders to be synched not just one folder?

Comment: Only *within the Dropbox folder.*

Comment: @SteveChambers I've updated my question. iCloud seems to have an inconvenient way of sharing folders. So you think Dropbox is better than Google drive and OneDrive?

Comment: How does this question relate to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389329/time-machine-sync-over-multiple-macs?

Comment: Also, the question right now is rather broad, can you add some focus by listing the requirements you have specifically?

Comment: @nohillside The other question was Time Machine related and after people suggested that time machine is not good I thought to make another question to know which cloud service is the best. I've updated my question, could you please check if it's good now or needs more details?

Comment: @nohillside Is it possible to reopen it after I updated it?

Comment: What does the third requirement (iPhone backup) have to do with the other two? File syncing/sharing is something rather different than iPhone backup. I even doubt that sycing and sharing require the same solution but that depends on details like whether the Macs are all in the same network, how often files need to be shared etc.

Comment: @nohillside How about now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107259/discussion-between-tak-and-nohillside).

Answer (score 2):

iCloud is better since you can get support from Apple. It’s also better since you can enable [local content caching](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-content-caching-on-mac-mchl3b6c3720/mac) which speeds things up 10x or much more for some cases.

OneDrive is getting better, so I would explore that if you like Microsoft.

No cloud sync is going to make everyone happy or not have issues or barf and choke. But I choose based on who I want to hire for support and what happens when their support fails me, which I will then have to learn or pay someone third party for help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107300/discussion-on-answer-by-bmike-sync-multiple-macs-together-which-is-better-iclou).